# Webpack 4's compiled `.mjs` dependency results in `ReferenceError: module is not defined`

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

After adding a function from graphql-tools into our bundle, we started getting a `ReferenceError: module is not defined` error from graphql-tools's dependency `iterall`.

Our webpack 4 is compiling a dependency's mjs file to this:

```
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
module.exports = __webpack_require__.p + "static/media/index.8485c181.mjs";
```

Have verified that aliasing the dependency specifically to the .js format fixes it, i.e. iterall:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    iterall: 'iterall/index.js',
  },
},
```

But this obviously isn't the best way to solve the problem

Is this an issue with our webpack config?